# Assign to itself: optimization or extraneous?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

So I was going through the glimg section of the unofficial OpenGL library and came across something I found strange. In one of the functions a pointer parameter is being assigned to itself and I can't see how this could be accomplishing anything. Does this somehow force memory into cache or is it something else? Possibly a bug?

```
static uint8 *resample_row_generic(uint8 *out, uint8 *in_near, uint8 *in_far, int w, int hs)
{
   // resample with nearest-neighbor
   int i,j;
   in_far = in_far;  // <-- here?
   for (i=0; i < w; ++i)
      for (j=0; j < hs; ++j)
         out[i*hs+j] = in_near[i];
   return out;
}
```

Comment: It's probably just to silence unused parameter warnings.

Comment: Without a statement `x=x`; some compilers would warn about unused variable, which may be an error according some coding conventions. This however is another kind of error (left value unused) according to some other rules in code analysis tools. A better working alternative is `(void)variable;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's there to suppress the warning that the parameter `in_far` is not used in the function.

Another way to suppress the warning is:

```
(void)in_far;
```

Comment: Can't you just leave out the name?

Comment: @aaronman Some compiler may generate a warning for unused parameters.

Comment: @aaronman  Yes. But this is an old trick that predated unnamed parameters.  Habits die hard.

Comment: @Gene well that makes sense because I would assume the open Gl code is pretty old

Comment: Ah of course! thank you now I feel dumb. It's funny though the way I came across this was that clang gives `warning: explicitly assigning a variable of type 'uint8 *' (aka 'unsigned char *') to itself [-Wself-assign]` so maybe the unnamed parameter or (void)in_far would be a better solution.

Comment: Isn't that just degrading performance for silencing a compiler warning? Isn't there any other method (like Java's `@SuppressWarning` annotation, maybe) for achieving that? Being OpenGL, every instruction you lose is a problem.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia A smart compiler may optimize this away, so the runtime performance isn't affected. There isn't such annotation in C although I'm not familiar with OpenGL.

Comment: @Gene: Unnamed parameters do not exist in C.  You are thinking of C++.

Comment: @DietrichEpp You're right. But my mistake wasn't thinking of C++, but remembering C prototypes where names are optional.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia no one has code for which "every instruction lost is a problem".

Comment: well maybe, but you would need to run your code a million times before it could make even a millisecond difference.. :P